# removing previous marker before adding new marker in Mapbox

Tags: angular, typescript, web, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I have below code to display markers in the place when the map loads via GeoJson data. It's working perfectly and the thing is I want to remove the previous map markers when adding new markers. Where I should make changes to work perfectly.

Here is the complete function

```
prepareGeoJsonData(data) {
    let features = [];
    let counter = 0;

    for (let val of data) {
      features.push({
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: val.address.geometry.border,
        center: val.address.geometry.center,
        properties: {
          center: val.address.geometry.center.coordinates,
          landUnitId: val.memberOf.parcel[0]
        },
        id: counter++,
      });
      //
code for marker customization
//
        let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(cords)
          // .setPopup(popup)
          .addTo(this._mapRef);
        this.markers.push(marker);
      }
    };
    return {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: features
    };
  }
```

Current Flow:

Page Loads -> Map Loads -> Markers Appear -> Apply filters -> New Markers Added -> Previous Markers **Still Present**

Required Flow:

Page Loads -> Map Loads -> Markers Appear -> Apply filters -> New Markers Added -> Previous Markers **Disappear**

Comment: Can you share a proper code because here I can't understand your `prepareGeoJsonData ` function, its appears it return nothing and the return is out of the function.
If you can try to share with us a fully functional snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming you are using google maps. Have you checked this url?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

TLDR;

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      this.markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
```

Comment: They're using Mapbox-GL-JS, not Google Maps.

Comment: I am using mapbox.
It has the function marker.remove
but it's not working fine, either my markers load or they don't load at all.

Comment: @JibranYousuf Did you figure this out? I am also dealing with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. I did some research but couldn't find any solution. There is a marker.remove() method in mapbox. Below is what I did.

```js
                                      // on click event, getting map data
                                      var clickMark = mapInner.on('click', (e) => {
                                        var coordinates = e.lngLat;
                                        
                                        // Create a new marker.
                                        var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                                        .setLngLat(coordinates)
                                        .addTo(mapInner);

                                       // Inner on click event to remove old marker
                                        mapInner.on('click', () => {
                                          try {
                                            marker.remove();
                                          }
                                          catch(err) {
                                            console.log(err)
                                          }
                                        });
                                        
                                        });
```